# How do we determine the values of $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The events $A$, $B$ and $C$ have to do with the same experiment and for them we know: $P(A\cup B) = 0.9$, $P(A\cup C) = 0.8$, $P(B\cup C) = 0.8$, $P(A\cap B) = 0.3$ , $P(A\cap C) = 0.3$, $P(B\cap C) = 0.3$ and $P(A\cup B\cup C) = 1$. Find $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C)$.

Comment: You would need to use basic formulas for things such as $P[A \cup B]$.  Write out a system of equalities and then solve for the unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

As @Michael has pointed out, you have the following system of equations to solve
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = 0.9\\\\
P(A) + P(C) - P(A\cap C) = 0.8\\\\
P(B) + P(C) - P(B\cap C) = 0.8
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
P(A) + P(B) - 0.3 = 0.9\\\\
P(A) + P(C) - 0.3 = 0.8\\\\
P(B) + P(C) - 0.3 = 0.8
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
P(A) + P(B) = 1.2\\\\
P(A) + P(C) = 1.1\\\\
P(B) + P(C) = 1.1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Once you find out the values of $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(C)$, you can make use of the following identity:
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap  C) + P(A\cap B\cap C)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?